# BufferedReader readLine() freeze while getting data from socket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter, bufferedwriter

i have this code on server side

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            LinkedList <String[]> temp = new LinkedList<String[]>();
            String cognome = "";
            String nome = "";
            while (!(cognome=reader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(cognome);
                nome = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(nome);
                temp.addLast(new String[]{cognome,nome});
                System.out.println("ricevuto il docente "+cognome+" "+nome);
            }
            mutex.acquire();
            for(;0<temp.size();)
                docenti.add(temp.removeFirst());
            mutex.release();
            if (isRunning.tryAcquire()){
                aggiungiDocenti();
                isRunning.release();
     }
```

Now, the server hangs in the line "while((cognome=reader.readLine())!=null), i tried to use PrintWriter (by using println(mex) and by using print(mex+"\r\n")) and to use BufferedWriter (using write(mex) and newLine()) but the server ever hangs on the while line... What's wrong with it? HEre is my actual client code:

```
        Socket s = new Socket(ip,Integer.parseInt(port));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        while (model.effectivilyCount()>0){
            writer.write(model.getValueAt(0, 0)+"\r\n");
            writer.write(model.getValueAt(0, 1)+"\r\n");
            model.removeRow(0);
        }
        writer.close();
        s.close();
```

Comment: what is `model` here?

Comment: Is there a negation in your condition `while (!(cognome=reader.readLine())!=null){` ? What's the value of `reader.ready()` ?

Comment: I wish devs would just stop using complex, compound expressions that are difficult to debug.  'cognome=reader.readLine()' should be in a line of its own so that, (with all optimization off), the intermediate results can be easily checked while single-stepping and the correct conclusions made.

Comment: model is a Table Model (where i extract data)... I noticed that if i set a breakpoint to String nome=""; when the breakpoint is stopped here, the client has sent everything yet... Is that possible? I Tried to let the client wait the server (with a reader/writer) but the readLine() freeze anyway. The problem is that readLine() doesn't read never one line
@CristianGreco the first negation is an error :P

Comment: @Martin James i agree with you, i tried yet to do a simple cognome=reader.readLine(); and it didn't work too... Seems like the writer writes to no one, cause i noticed i get the writer writes all authors in the model while the reader hasn't received strings (but they are connected in the same socket)

Comment: I suggest you to use a `PrintWriter` and use `println` not `print` with `\r\n`. I don't know what `model` is that may cause something wrong but I can suggest you to call `writer.flush()` just after your `print`s in each loop, this will force the output to the network stack.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès you method worked... I needed to use just one flush() on the first message, and everything works after it O.o.. Misteriously java

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès how to upvote it? I think you should use "Answer question" on the bottom... so i can vote your answer :)